# How to separate values from string into columns in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
tlb (Text)               value(Integer)   cost (numeric)
150;itema;section;shelf      5                0.5
120;itemb;shelf;box          5                2.3
151;itemf;section;shelf      5                1.5
```

I want to convert this table into this table:

```
a        b         c        d   value   cost
150    itema    section    shelf   5    0.5
120    itemb    shelf      box     5    2.3
151    itemf    section    shelf   5    1.5
```

basically break the `tlb` column to 4 different columns .

The structure of `tlb` is always the same `string;string;string;string`

How can i do that?

Comment: you can use `split_part` eg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `split_part`, Eg:

```
t=# with s as (select '150;itema;section;shelf'::text d)
select
  split_part(d,';',1) a
, split_part(d,';',2) b
, split_part(d,';',3) c
, split_part(d,';',4) d
from s;
  a  |   b   |    c    |   d
-----+-------+---------+-------
 150 | itema | section | shelf
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

show this:

```
select
exe2.arr[1] as a,
exe2.arr[2] as b,
exe2.arr[3] as c,
exe2.arr[4] as d
from
(
    select
    exe.x,
    string_to_array(exe.x,';') as arr
    from
    (
        select
        '150;itema;section;shelf' as x
        union select
        '120;itemb;shelf;box' as x
        union select
        '151;itemf;section;shelf' as x
    ) exe
) exe2
```